# React route v6 have NavBar for only some routes

Tags: reactjs, routes, navbar, router

In react-router-dom v5 I was able to do this in order for the NavBar to only show when a user was logged in and using a relevant link (not the HomePage). I can't figure out how to do this in v6. When I do something similar I get a "No route found" error for the /meds and /hist paths.

V5

```
<Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
    <Route
        path={'/(.+)'}
        render={() => (
        <div>
            <NavBar />
            <Container className="main">
                <Private exact path="/meds" component={MedicationDashboard} />
                ...
```

V6

```
<Routes>
<Route exact path='/' element={<HomePage />} />
<Route
    path={'/(.+)'}
    render={() => (
    <div>
        <NavBar />
        <div>
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/meds' element={<Medications />} />
                <Route path='/hist' element={<History />} />
            </Routes>
        </div>
    </div>
    )}
    />
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 4):

Following to [react router v6 docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes)
You can do it this way:

**App.tsx**

```
<Routes>
    <Route index element={<HomePage />} />
    <Route element={<NavbarLayout />} />
        <Route path='/meds' element={<Medications />} />
        <Route path='/hist' element={<History />} />
    </Route>
</Routes>
```

You will need to create component to store layout, let's call it NavbarLayout.tsx. Source code should looks like:

**NavbarLayout.tsx**

```
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

export default function NavbarLayout () {
    return (
        <div>
            <NavBar />
            <div>
                <Outlet />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Great response, just one point to make. The `<Route` for the `NavbarLayout` shouldn't end with `... />} />`. It should not have the closing tag and should rather be `... />} >`.